# Set specific multiindex from scratch

Tags: dataframe, indexing, multi-index

my task is the following: I need to build several tables in forms of dataframes from scratch. In particular, each table is always the same for every Identifier (sort of summary statistics table). For example:

```
 result= {'Value':[mean_t,mean_t_1,mean_diff_lev, mean_diff_log],
             'T-stat':[np.NaN,np.NaN,t_diff_lev, t_diff_log],
             'Type':['XL','XL','XL', 'XL']}
 result=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result,orient='index',
                                  columns=['Square_t','Square_t_1',
                                           'Mean diff','Mean diff log'])
```

gives me this as a result:

```
        Square_t Square_t_1 Mean diff Mean diff log
Value   502.123    533.324  -31.2018    -0.0567523
T-stat      NaN        NaN  -3.33098      -5.38749
Type         XL         XL        XL            XL
```

I have a function that calculates all the values used there and at the end it creates the dataframe given above from a dictionary of values. I need to be able to set a multiindex which consists of two components: the first (or outer) one is the identifier (say 'Roger') and the second (or inner) is given by what I already have, i.e. the list `['Value','T-Stat'.'Type']`. The result should look like this:

```
             Square_t Square_t_1 Mean diff Mean diff log
Roger Value   502.123    533.324  -31.2018    -0.0567523
      T-stat      NaN        NaN  -3.33098      -5.38749
      Type         XL         XL        XL            XL
```

or this:

```
ID    Var      Square_t Square_t_1 Mean diff Mean diff log
Roger Value     502.123    533.324  -31.2018    -0.0567523
      T-stat        NaN        NaN  -3.33098      -5.38749
      Type           XL         XL        XL            XL
```

The objective is then being able to build a bigger dataframe for by appending or concatenating different dataframes with different ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. The easiest way is to use the pandas method `concat`.
Instead of creating a dataframe with multiindex for every ID, it is better to create a dataframe without ID for every single ID, creating all dataframes and, after keeping track of the various IDs in a list, we can simply concatenate all the single-ID dataframes altogether. Let us says we have two dataframes `df1,df2`the type :

```
        Square_t Square_t_1 Mean diff Mean diff log
Value   502.123    533.324  -31.2018    -0.0567523
T-stat      NaN        NaN  -3.33098      -5.38749
Type         XL         XL        XL            XL
```

for the IDs `['Roger','Kyle']`. The we run:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=['Roger','Kyle'])
```

and the result will be indeed a multiindexed dataframe:

```
              Square_t Square_t_1 Mean diff Mean diff log
Roger  Value   430.855    454.733  -23.8778    -0.0492182
       T-stat      NaN        NaN  -3.48394      -5.37168
       Type         XL         XL        XL            XL
Kyle   Value   721.824     735.67   -13.846    -0.0192327
       T-stat      NaN        NaN  -1.93132      -2.74519
       Type         XL         XL        XL            XL

pd.concat([df1,df2],keys=['Roger','Kyle']),index

MultiIndex([('Roger',  'Value'),
            ('Roger', 'T-stat'),
            ('Roger',  'Type'),
            ( 'Kyle',  'Value'),
            ( 'Kyle', 'T-stat'),
            ( 'Kyle',  'Type')],
           )
```